# How to get measured width/height when using fillparent

Tags: android

My imageview is set to Wrap Content. And to it I set a bitmap. 
Now if the bitmap is bigger than devices maxwidth/maxheight the imageview is resized to the parent size to acomodate the bitmap as best as possible.

The problem I am having is if the bitmap is smaller than the imageview. In this case I would also like the bitmap/imageview to be resized to use the available space still keeping aspect ratio.

Now this can be achieved with using FILL_PARENT on the imageview and setting 
        ScaleType.FIT_CENTER

But if the imageview is set to fill parent then the

```
getMeasuredWidth/getMeasuredHeight
```

will return the size of the whole imageview and not the bitmap that is in the imageview.

How can I get smaller bitmaps using the whole view whilst keeping aspect ratio and still get their measured width and height?

Comment: It is not an answer but a comment that 'fill_parent' is deprecated. Since API Level 8 and higher better use 'match_parent'.

Comment: If you set adjustViewBounds to true, then ImageView height and width will be adjust to bitmap width and height.